# Gauldur's ghost is just standing there, how can I progress?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I read online that at this point during the quest Forbidden Legend the ghost of archmage Gauldur should fix the amulet, but now the dude is just standing there frozen:

[image]

The biggest problem is that I cannot even get out of the room. I only have one saved game, and, of course, it's after I killed the brothers.

I've tried rebooting the console, re-inserting the disk, closing the application - nothing is working so far. I also tried just waiting.. to no avail.

Have any of you experienced something similar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden Legend Quest: Gauldur is immobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43832/forbidden-legend-quest-gauldur-is-immobile). That is for the PC, but some answers might work in your case (like attacking the ghost of Gauldur).

Comment: Looks like they're having the same problem. Read their solutions but unfortunately they aren't working for me. Best thing to do is load from a quick save I guess :(